# How to add pagination in Astra theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am using Astra wordpress theme and if there is more than 5 articles on page it should be bottom banner with 1- 2- 3 like pagination. For that i have tried with `WP-PageNavi` plugin but looking for right place to insert `<?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>`. Any idea about it ?or any work around ?

Answer (score 1):

Check 2 things:

1. Wp-admin > Settings > Reading > Blog pages show at most. <= Make this 5 or less for your case.
2. If the above doesn't work can you try using the astra_number_pagination() method instead? As Astra says that this will output numbered pagination.

These methods should work ideally, if not let me know.

Comment: Thanks. But i really don't know where to put `astra_number_pagination()` ? Can you guide through steps?

Comment: Did you check the 1st step? possibly that'll automatically show you pagination in Astra theme.

Comment: Solved it.. Actually i accidentally added post as Menu category (